# Getting object ID in controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stacked.

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user_id = current_user.id
    @event.repeat_id = @event.id
    @event.save
end
```

Here's my create method, where i need to set repeat_id of created event= usual id of created event. But this code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: You've not saved the event yet so it doesn't have an id yet.  Therefore `@event.repeat_id = @event.id` sets the repeat_id to nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @event.user_id = current_user.id
  if @event.save
    @event.update_attributes(:repeat_id => @event.id)
    @event.save
  end
end
```

Comment: @Prashant4020 whats the point of saving after `update_attributes`. You are  overdoing it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @event.user_id = current_user.id
  @event.save  
end
```

In your `event.rb` model add an `after_create` callback

```
after_create :assign_repeat_id

def assign_repeat_id
  self.repeat_id = id
  save
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure it as:

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.user_id = current_user.id
    @event.update_attributes(:repeat_id => @event.id) if @event.save
end
```

Key point here is, you cannot have `@event.id` unless its present in the database i.e. its saved.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like this:

```
def create
  @event = Event.create(event_params)
  @event.update_attributes(user_id: current_user.id, repeat_id: @event.id)
  @event.save
end
```

Your event doesn't have an id to duplicate until it exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
def create
 @event = Event.new(event_params)
 @event.user_id = current_user.id
if @event.save
 @event.update_column(:repeat_id,@event.id) 
end
end
```